# Having Difficulty Migrating from Nuxt 2 to Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, migration, nuxtjs3

I'm facing difficulties while migrating from Nuxt 2 to Nuxt 3, and I have a question.

Currently, in Nuxt 2, I am handling authentication through middleware. As you can see in the code below, I am using app to work with cookies and Axios. However, it seems that in Nuxt 3, there is no app.

How should I modify this code for Nuxt 3?

```js
// middleware/auth.js
export default async function (app) {
    try {
        console.log('Loading...');

        const csrfToken = await fetchCsrfToken(app);
        const authResult = await checkAuth(app, "accessToken", csrfToken);

        app.store.commit('setAuthResult', authResult.res);

        if(authResult.res){
          const userInfo = await getUserInfo(app, csrfToken);

          app.store.commit('setUserInfo', userInfo.res);
          console.log(userInfo);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during authentication check:', error);
    }
}

function ajaxRequest(app, url, method, data) {
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    if (data) {
        if (data.token) {
            headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${data.token}`;
        }
        if (data.csrfToken) {
            headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = data.csrfToken;
        }
    }

    const axiosConfig = {
        method,
        url,
        headers,
        data,
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        app.$axios(axiosConfig)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    resolve(response.data);
                } else {
                    switch (response.status) {
                        case 400:
                            reject(new Error('Bad Request: ' + response.data));
                            break;
                        case 401:
                            reject(new Error('Unauthorized: ' + response.data));
                            break;
                        case 403:
                            reject(new Error('Forbidden: ' + response.data));
                            break;
                        default:
                            reject(new Error('Request failed with status: ' + response.status));
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(new Error('Request error: ' + error));
            });
    });
}


async function fetchCsrfToken(app) {
    try {
        const response = await app.$axios.$get('/getcsrf');
        const tokenInfo = response.token;

        console.log('CSRF token stored in Cookies:', tokenInfo);

        return tokenInfo;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching CSRF token:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}


async function checkAuth(app, tokenType, csrfToken) {
    let token;
    if (tokenType === 'accessToken') {
        token = app.$cookies.get('accessToken');
    } else if (tokenType === 'refreshToken') {
        token = app.$cookies.get('refreshToken');
    } else {
        console.error('Invalid tokenType:', tokenType);
        return;
    }

    try {
        console.log(tokenType + " call");
        const res = await ajaxRequest(app, '/check-auth', 'POST', {
            token,
            csrfToken,
        });

        if (tokenType === 'accessToken' && res === 'Refresh token required') {
            await checkAuth(app, 'refreshToken', csrfToken);
            return false;
        }

        return {res};
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error checking authentication:', error);
    }
}


async function getUserInfo(app, csrfToken) {
    const token = app.$cookies.get('accessToken');
    try {
        const res = await ajaxRequest(app, "/user-info", "POST", {
            token,
            csrfToken,
        });

        return {res};
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error checking authentication:', error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method [`useNuxtApp`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-nuxt-app):

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(() => {
  const nuxt = useNuxtApp(); // nuxt app is here
  const vue = nuxt.vueApp; // vue app is here
});
```

Comment: Is it more appropriate to handle authentication and authorization functionality by intercepting axios requests when the layout is mounted rather than in middleware?

Comment: @JunYoungMoon In my opinion, middleware remains the optimal option for authentication as it appears to be the key design objective of middleware. Have you encountered any problems in this regard?

Comment: Yes, I agree that middleware is considered a suitable option for implementing authentication. However, it's not that there's a problem, but I've noticed that many people intercept axios or fetch to implement authentication while going through various codebases.